# R how to select functions between conflicting libraries

Tags: r, package, conflicting-libraries

When writing scripts on R,

I had trouble choosing functions with overlapping packages.

For example,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
~~~~~
```

And in the console,

```
-- Conflicts ---------------------------- tidyverse_conflicts() ---
x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
x dplyr::lag() masks stats::lag()
~~~~
```

How can I select the right functions?
For example, I want "filter()" from dplyr and lag() from stats.

*p.s. I don't want to write library() every time

Comment: The code is literally already in your question. `dplyr::filter` refers to function `filter` from package dplyr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `dplyr::filter` every time, we can use the [{conflicted} package](https://conflicted.r-lib.org/).

```r
library(dplyr)
conflict_prefer("filter", "dplyr")
```